# Как выровнять динамически высоту у 3 TextView

Tags: android, android-textview

Мне нужно реализовать данный элемент.

[image]

Я сделал его с помощью трёх TextView в ConstraintLyaout, привязав их стороны друг к другу

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/increment_left"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_grey"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:layout_width="40sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/decrement_right"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_cross_delete"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/price"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/price" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

и переопределив `android:backgroud` для первого элемента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="34dp" android:width="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="#F3F3F3" />
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10.0dip" android:topLeftRadius="10dip" />
</shape>
```

Второго

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="34dp" android:width="30dp" />
    <solid android:color="#F3F3F3" />
</shape>
```

И третьего

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="34dp" android:width="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="#F3F3F3" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10.0dip" android:topRightRadius="10dip" />
</shape>
```

Проблема возникает если название(тескт в первом элементе) слишком длинный и элемент автоматически растягивается по высоте, остальные два естественно этого не делают. Возможно ли как то программно синхронизировать? Выставлять `height` у 2 и 3 го `TextView` такой же как и у первого?
Я пробовал при присвоении значения `setText()` также присваивать `setHeight()` для 2 и 3 - го, но видимо свойство если и изменяется, то видимо позже при отрисовке.

Comment: используйте guideline для ConstraintLayout

Comment: Привяжите так же высоту элементов и выставьте android:layout_height="0dp"